# Understanding why $f_\Psi(\psi) = f_\Theta(g^{-1}(\psi))\left|\frac{d}{d\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)\right|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm reading a book on Bayesian statistics and I came across the following:

*Suppose that $\Psi = g(\Theta)$ and that $f$ is a density function. Then $f_\Psi(\psi) = f_\Theta(g^{-1}(\psi))\bigg|\dfrac{d}{d\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)\bigg|$.*

**Question:** Why is this true? I can't find the appropriate theorem do justify this, and I can't figure it out myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) on the matter. Probably doesn't sufficiently address "why", but may be useful nonetheless.

Comment: Note that $g$ needs to be monotonic for the above to be true.

Comment: You wrote "and that $f$ is a density function." But then after that you never referred to that particular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assumed $g$ is invertible. If $g$ is continuous, that can happen only if $g$ is strictly monotone. So here I will consider the case where $g$ is strictly increasing. In that case $g^{-1}$ is also strictly increasing, so $\dfrac d {d\psi} g^{-1}(\psi)\ge 0$ for all $\psi$ (possibly being equal to $0$ at some isolated points).

We have the c.d.f. $F_\Psi(\psi) = \Pr(\Psi \le \psi),$ and then
\begin{align}
f_\Psi(\psi) & = \frac d {d\psi} F_\Psi(\psi) = \frac d {d\psi} \Pr( g(\Theta) \le \psi) = \frac d {d\psi} \Pr(\Theta \le g^{-1}(\psi)) = \frac d {d\psi} F_\Theta(g^{-1}(\psi)) \\[10pt]
& = f_\Theta(g^{-1}(\psi)) \cdot \frac d {d\psi} g^{-1}(\psi) \quad \text{by the chain rule.}
\end{align}
The decreasing case is done similarly; some inequalities get inverted.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I realized that you used $\Theta$ at the last minute. Simply replace $X$ with $\Theta$ in my answer below in the context of your question.)

Suppose $\Psi = g(X)$ is **(strictly) monotonic** with $g^{-1}$ differentiable. Note also that $X$ and $\Psi$ are assumed to be continuous random variables.

We find the density (PDF) of $\Psi$ by finding first the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $\Phi$ and differentiating the CDF.

Observe
$$F_{\Psi}(\psi) = \mathbb{P}(\Psi \leq \psi) = \mathbb{P}(g(X) \leq \psi)\text{.}$$

**Case 1**. Suppose $g$ is **strictly increasing**. Then its inverse $g^{-1}$ is also increasing.

Consider the event $\{g(X) \leq \psi\}$.

[image]

The corresponding values of $X$ such that $g(X) \leq \psi$ are thus those where $X \leq g^{-1}(\psi)$.

[image]

Hence,

$$F_{\Psi}(\psi) = \mathbb{P}(g(X) \leq \psi) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq g^{-1}(\psi)) = F_{X}(g^{-1}(\psi))\text{.}$$
and differentiating (don't forget the chain rule), we obtain:
$$F_{\Psi}(\psi) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(\psi))\cdot \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)$$
Since $g^{-1}$ is strictly increasing, it follows that $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi) > 0$, so $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi) = \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)\right|$.

**Case 2**. Suppose $g$ is **strictly decreasing**. Then its inverse $g^{-1}$ is also decreasing.

Consider the event $\{g(X) \leq \psi\}$.

[image]

As we can see above, the corresponding values of $X$ such that $g(X) \leq \psi$ are those where $X \geq g^{-1}(\psi)$. Hence,

$$F_{\Psi}(\psi) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq g^{-1}(\psi)) = 1 - F_{X}(g^{-1}(\psi))\text{.}$$
Differentiating and applying the chain rule, we obtain
$$f_{\Psi}(\psi) = -f_{X}(g^{-1}(\psi)) \cdot \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)$$
**but** notice that in this case, $g^{-1}$ is **decreasing** so $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi) < 0$. Notice the negative coefficient with $f_{\Psi}$. This would this turn $\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)$ into its positive form; hence, we have
$$f_{\Psi}(\psi) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(\psi)) \cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\psi}g^{-1}(\psi)\right|$$
In both cases ($g$ strictly increasing, $g$ strictly decreasing), the above equation is true.